# Anonymisation resilient to key leak

Tags: keys, anonymity

### Problem statement

[Elbonian](http://dilbert.com/search_results?page=16&terms=elbonia) citizens have been issued a card holding a random $B_j\in\{0,1\}^b$, $0\le j<2^n$, $b\ge n+20$ (representative example $b=64$, $n=28$). The habit has grown to use this identifier to designate a person in the computer systems for health care, driving license, taxes, libraries, banking, fidelity accounts, dating services...
A new privacy law requires that all databases, including previously existing, containing data derived from the $B_j$ field, now hold it in a manner such that cross-referencing of databases used for different purposes is hard, even in case of leak of the secrets used for the databases to be matched.

More precisely, a database should store $C_j\in\{0,1\}^c$ deterministically computed as $C_j=F(K,B_j)$ where $K$ is a key used for a particular database, and the public definition of $F$ includes a constant work factor adjusted such that computing $C_j=F(K,B_j)$ requires a significant but feasible amount of work.

An adversary **knowing the keys** $K$ and $K'$ for two databases, knowing all $C_j=F(K,B_j)$ and $C'_j=F(K',B_j)$ (but not the random $B_j$), and assumed bound to computing power allowing to evaluate $2^w$ times the function $F$, with $w\le b$ (representative example $w=40$), can trivially explore $2^w$ values of $B_j$ and expect to find about $2^{n+w-b}$ matches ($2^4$ with our example values), putting each user at a risk $2^{w-b}$ of being matched ($2^{-24}$ with our example values). **A system is acceptable only if the best attacks are less than *twice* as efficient as this brute force attack**.
***Update***: The $w$ parameter covers spending extra time, and *technological* improvements by massive parallelization and ASICs. The adversary is free to spend that computing power as wanted, including trying to walk back from the $C_j$ to the $B_j$; or (as pointed by cpast in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24044/555#comment54596_24044)) finding an *algorithmic* way to compute $F$ faster in the forward direction for many $B_j$ at a time.

An adversary not knowing the key of a particular database should be unable to make matches for that database or predict $C_j$ from $B_j$ better than random, including for a huge number of evaluations of $F$ (say, $2^{128}$); that's relatively easy, for the width of $K$ is not constrained.

$F$ must be such that collisions among $C_j$ is impossible; or at least highly unlikely for the existing $B_j$. That is, for any $K$, odds that there exists $j,j'$ with $0\le j<j'<2^n$ and $F(K,B_j)=F(K,B_{j'})$ should be at most $2^{-r}$ (say $r=16$, which accounts for $2^{4}$ governmental databases for most Elbonians and a residual risk of $2^{-12}$ that any governmental agency gets ridiculed).

If it turned out to help, it would be fine that $K$ is constructed in a special manner involving secrets assumed not known to adversaries (e.g. is the product of two large random secret primes); however choosing $K$ can not depend on the $B_j$.

### Questions

1. **What's the lowest** $c$ (width of the field stored in the database) possible, and matching function $F$ (with its key generation procedure if it's not just random), for given $b,n,w,r$? We are interested in something better than $c=2n+r-1$ of the trivial construction, given below.
2. **What is the highest** $w$ (adversary work bound) possible (and matching function $F$ and key generation) **if we set** $c=b$ (which would greatly simplify the transition by being transparent to most software using the database), for given $b,n,r$ if that is relevant?

### Trivial construction

A trivial construction use a [key stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) function like [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) to construct a slow *random function*. We define $C_j=F(K,B_j)$ as the truncation to $c$ bits of the result of PBKDF2 with

- HMAC using SHA-256 as the PRF;
- $B_j$ as password;
- a random 128-bit key $K$ as salt;
- iteration count as high as functionally tolerable;
- $\lceil c/8\rceil$ as the output length in octet.

It is possible that there will be collisions, but we have control over this using $c$. Odds that there exists a collision among $2^n$ outputs is $1-(1-2^{-c})^{2^n(2^n-1)/2}$, which is less than $2^{2n-c-1}$, thus $c=2n+r-1$ is enough to keep collision odds less than $2^{-r}$, as required.

Regardless of $w$, this is precisely at the limit of brute force given in the question: for $2^w$ evaluations, an adversary can expect $2^{n+w-b}$ matches, putting each user at a risk $2^{w-b}$. A better key stretching function like [Scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) will not change this, but will make it significantly more costly for the adversary to make the $2^w$ evaluations.

---

Note: yes, the system is vulnerable to creating a list of issued $B_j$ in any place where they are read from a card, or from an old database; but it turns out that, including in non-fictitious countries, authorities responsible for defining rules protecting anonymity are willing to ignore that risk, or otherwise said want to first solve the most glaring problems in a pragmatic way.

Comment: I assume that $F$ must be defined so that one cannot short-circuit the work factor -- if an attacker has a list of $x$ ordered pairs $(K,B)$, it must take the attacker around $x$ times as long to compute $F$ on the whole list (or $x/k$ if they have $k$ computers at their disposal) as to compute one evaluation of $F$. Basically, you can't let the work factor be short-circuited by an attacker computing many pairs (so if the work factor is like "start by doing this chain of operations on $K$", that's no good b/c I can just do it *once* for a given $K$ and store the result). Is that correct?